# Country Bug ("Canada") in Careers Search

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Every couple of weeks, I used Careers to search for all jobs in Canada.

I always type "Canada" into the search box, which usually returns a few pages of results.

I tried again this morning, and this was the result:

[image: Screenshot]

As much as I would like to work in Spain, the Canada that I am referring to is the country, not the town in Spain.

I was still able to do find some jobs by searching `<City Name>, Canada`, but I liked it better when I could just search `Canada`.

Is this a bug?  Or has the search functionality switched?

I think it might be a bug, because in the `where` field under refine search, the place holder texts says I may specify a country:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1, enter `"Canada, NA"` and you will get results back for Canada,

Comment: Thanks, I had tried "Canada, North America", which returned all ~1500 jobs in North America.

Comment: Is this a bug, or a badly worded text hint? You could also read it as "(city, country) OR (zip code)". Yay for ambiguous commas!

Comment: Looks like the first priority is a city, and there is [this city](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villanueva_de_la_Ca%C3%B1ada) in Spain indeed. Appears to be problem with Yahoo API that thinks "Cañada" is equals to "Canada".

Comment: @ShadowWizard the priority is supposed to be most commonly referred to area, but it's not always ordered well when it comes to us and we clearly have bugs in our selection algorithm.

Comment: @NickLarsen got it, so actually it's a good thing the bug is on "your" side as it's easier to fix than waiting for Yahoo to fix their bugs. :)

Comment: I've given up on Yahoo fixing things, coming up with ideas on how to skirt around their issues in the meantime.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the litmus test for whether it's something we should be able to fix vs a Yahoo geocoding issue is to hit maps.yahoo.com and type the same search text in.  If you get on their site what you get on our site, there isn't much we can do.  If you get what you want on their site, we should be able to fix it.

Comment: Remind me of the Wheel of Blame, @Nick and the result is... you can fix that! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed.

You should be able to type "Canada" and get the expected search results.

Thank you for the report !